# Order by in CTE/Set Operators

Tags: sql, sql-server

So, my business need is to get top 30 customers (with ties) every day, and every customer can be selected only once per week. So I made three queries, every works the same (fine), but I have doubts on the theoretical ground.

1) The first method, when I have two CTE and select TOP 30 from these two groups during the expressions which is part of set operation (EXCEPT), but - as far as I know - we shouldn't use order by during set operations, right? It's working perfectly BTW

```
WITH A  
AS (select dbo.customerentities.customer_id, first_name, last_name, tel, 
sale.sum_sale 
from dbo.CustomerSubscriptions ---check for client's subscriptions 
left join dbo.CustomerEntities on dbo.CustomerSubscriptions.customer_id = 
dbo.CustomerEntities.customer_id 
left join (select customer_id, sum (sale) as sum_sale, from dbo.OrderTable 
where sale_date between CONVERT(DATE, getdate() - 2) and convert(date, 
getdate() - 1) group by customer_id) as sale on CustomerEntities.customer_id 
= sale.customer_id
where not sale.sum_sale is null), 

B  
AS (select dbo.customerentities.customer_id, first_name, last_name, tel, 
sale.sum_sale 
from dbo.CustomerSubscriptions ---check for client's subscriptions
left join dbo.CustomerEntities on dbo.CustomerSubscriptions.customer_id = 
dbo.CustomerEntities.customer_id 
left join (select customer_id, sum (sale) as sum_sale, from dbo.OrderTable 
where sale_date between CONVERT(DATE, getdate() - 1) and convert(date, 
getdate()) group by customer_id) as sale on CustomerEntities.customer_id 
= sale.customer_id
where not sale.sum_sale is null)

select *from B where customer_id in
(select top 30 with ties customer_id from B order by sale desc
except
select top 30 with ties customer_id from A order by sale desc)
order by sale desc
```

2) The second one is nearly the same, but I've decided to select top 30 on the CTE level, but once again - CTE is relation, right? So we shouldn't use order by in relation? Otherwise, it works.

```
WITH A  
AS (select top 30 with ties dbo.customerentities.customer_id, first_name, 
last_name, tel, 
sale.sum_sale 
from dbo.CustomerSubscriptions ---check for client's subscriptions 
left join dbo.CustomerEntities on dbo.CustomerSubscriptions.customer_id = 
dbo.CustomerEntities.customer_id 
left join (select customer_id, sum (sale) as sum_sale, from dbo.OrderTable 
where sale_date between CONVERT(DATE, getdate() - 2) and convert(date, 
getdate() - 1) group by customer_id) as sale on CustomerEntities.customer_id 
= sale.customer_id
where not sale.sum_sale is null
order by sale desc), 

B  
AS (select top 30 with ties dbo.customerentities.customer_id, first_name, 
last_name, tel, 
sale.sum_sale 
from dbo.CustomerSubscriptions ---check for client's subscriptions
left join dbo.CustomerEntities on dbo.CustomerSubscriptions.customer_id = 
dbo.CustomerEntities.customer_id 
left join (select customer_id, sum (sale) as sum_sale, from dbo.OrderTable 
where sale_date between CONVERT(DATE, getdate() - 1) and convert(date, 
getdate()) group by customer_id) as sale on CustomerEntities.customer_id 
= sale.customer_id
where not sale.sum_sale is null
order by sale desc)

select *from B where customer_id in
(select customer_id from B 
except
select customer_id from A )
order by sale desc
```

3) The third method is the worst one, but I have no doubts to that.

```
select A.customer_id, A.first_name, A.last_name, A.tel, A.sum_sale
from (select top 30 with ties dbo.customerentities.customer_id, first_name, 
last_name, tel, 
sale.sum_sale 
from dbo.CustomerSubscriptions ---check for client's subscriptions
left join dbo.CustomerEntities on dbo.CustomerSubscriptions.customer_id = 
dbo.CustomerEntities.customer_id 
left join (select customer_id, sum (sale) as sum_sale, from dbo.OrderTable 
where sale_date between CONVERT(DATE, getdate() - 1) and convert(date, 
getdate()) group by customer_id) as sale on CustomerEntities.customer_id 
= sale.customer_id
where not sale.sum_sale is null
order by sale desc) as A
left join (select top 30 with ties dbo.customerentities.customer_id, 
first_name, 
last_name, tel, 
sale.sum_sale 
from dbo.CustomerSubscriptions ---check for client's subscriptions 
left join dbo.CustomerEntities on dbo.CustomerSubscriptions.customer_id = 
dbo.CustomerEntities.customer_id 
left join (select customer_id, sum (sale) as sum_sale, from dbo.OrderTable 
where sale_date between CONVERT(DATE, getdate() - 2) and convert(date, 
getdate() - 1) group by customer_id) as sale on CustomerEntities.customer_id 
= sale.customer_id
where not sale.sum_sale is null
order by sale desc) as B on A.customer_id = B.customer_id
where B.customer_id is null --- to exclude customers which already received 
--- bonus day earlier
order by sale desc
```

So my question is - should I use the third method or I can easily use top-order with CTE/set operations?

Comment: Your queries are barely legible.  As a general rule, you should _always_ use `ORDER BY` if you use `TOP`.

Comment: Well, of course I know that I should use order by when I use TOP - I've did it every time above. My question is totally different - can I use Top with order by IN CTE or drugin SET OPERATIONS?

Comment: Just adding to @TimBiegeleisen’s comment. `TOP` without `ORDER BY` is not determined, as there is no guaranteed implicit order, so the top 30 could be any 30. Unlike most other DBMS, Microsoft will not let you use `ORDER BY` in a CTE, a Sub Query or a View _unless_ you either append an `OFFSET` clause (for more modern versions) or add a `TOP` (you can’t do both).

Comment: You may use `ORDER BY` inside a CTE, but it is sort of useless, because when you query that CTE, the order would just be lost.

Comment: Well, @Manngo, I use MS SERVER and I use order by in CTE and it works. So that's why I've asked this question. First, I've did with third method, but I hate that method so I've decided to checki with put top/order in expressions during except. When it worked, I decided to check also with putting top/order in CTE and it still works.

Comment: @Karol Re-read my second comment.

Comment: If you are using SSMS, you can put all three together in a single script and show the estimated execution plan (ctrl-L). If the query results are truly the same, and if the execution costs are roughly the same, the it’s a matter of choosing the version that you thing might be more maintainable or understandable.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, it's exactly what I thought too (and what I've learned too). But it works and that's why I decide to start this thread. Oh, beside these business thing, I've just made that CTE, and just write select * from A, and it give 30 top results (so that's why it works with set opeartion).

Comment: Yeah, @Manngo, I know. It's not about that, but looks like I've found solution - https://sqltimes.wordpress.com/2014/11/26/sql-server-common-table-expression-cte-with-order-by-clause/ So my solution was fine and no need to be astonished (because first, I've thought that you can't use order by in CTE, but with TOP it works). Same with set operations, apparently.

Comment: OK, I've checked without top and it doesn't work (and should doesn't work), so Top was solution (https://imgur.com/a/nmx5BNn) and that's why it works. So here is another question - is it work with LIMIT too on MySQL? I can't check it by myself. Thanks guys for discussion!

Comment: I think there are simpler ways to solve this problem, but I find the code rather impenetrable.  Suggestion:  Ask another question.  In this version, have a single table that has the result of the data after your joins.  Give a simple example of what you mean by "top with ties" and "once per week".